# Adapting an existing django site for modal forms

Tags: django, modal-dialog

I have a site which uses the urls to add/edit/view records to the database. These pass the information to another template for data entry. I'm now looking at modal forms - at the moment we have used css, rather than the Django modal forms.

My question, which is basic, is it possible to keep the urls and templates but embed them in the modal? This way we can keep the same code and migrate to modals without recoding the views.

I'm looking for a clear simple documentation for this - so please send me any good links.

For a basic example (we have more complex views):

template storage

```
{% extends 'storage/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content%}
{% include "mainheader.html" %}
{% include "storage/submenu.html" %}
<div class="container top">
  <div class="row">
    {% for storage in storage.all %}
    <a class="text-light" href="{% url 'depot:detailstorage' storage.store_id %}">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <!--div class="card-header">{{ storage.store_name }}</div-->
          <div class="card-body"  style="">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{ storage.store_name }}</h5>
            <img class="card-img-top p-3" src="{{ storage.icon_desc.icon.url }}" /></a>
            <p class="card-text" style = "font-size:0.7em;">{{ storage.address_1 }} {{ storage.address_2 }} {{ storage.city }} {{ storage.region }} {{ storage.zip }} {{ storage.country }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

template create storage

```
{% extends 'storage/base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
{% include "mainheader.html" %}
{% include "storage/submenu.html" %}
<div class="container top">
  <h4 class="kap">Storage</h4>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}

                   <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-dark mt-3t">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

views
storage

```
def allstorage(request):
    allstorage = Storage.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'storage/allstorage.html',
    {
        'storage':allstorage
    })
```

create_storage

```
def createstorage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StorageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.created_by = request.user
            # post.modified_by = request.user
            # post.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('depot:allstorage')
    else:
        form = StorageForm()
    return render(request, 'storage/create_storage.html', {'form': form})
```

urls

```
re_path(r'^storage/$', allstorage, name='allstorage'),
url(r'^storage/createstorage/$', createstorage, name='createstorage'),
```

(yes, we also need to update all urls to path/re_path)

Comment: What are "Django modal forms"? Is this some external package you are looking at? Or do you mean *Model* forms?

Comment: It's a Django package, but more of a secondary tangent at this stage. The main question, as above, is can we enable modal without needing to re-write the views/urls since we were using separate pages before. https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/